# How to activate an if statement with a range of numbers in swift

Tags: swift

I am making a game where if a variable is equal to one number in a range of numbers an if statement will take effect. e.g. if var1 = 4, then the if will activate but it will also give an output if var1 was to equal 5, 6, 7 or 8 for example (the numbers in a set range).

I currently have no code for this part of the game so I won't be able to add it to this question.

Sorry if this question is badly explained or too vague to answer, I am new to stack overflow. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the best way to do this is using Swift's powerful `switch` statements.

You can do this:

```
let x = 5

switch(x){
case 0..<4:
    // Will match 0-3
    print("one")
case 4..<10:
    // will match 4-9
    print("two")
case 10...:
    // will match >= 10
    print("three")
default:
    print("other")
}
```

EDIT:
If that's too robust for your situation, you can also do this:

```
if (0..<4).contains(x){
    print("yes")
}else {
    print("no")
}
```

or even more simply:

```
if x >= 0 && x < 4{
    print("yes")
}else {
    print("no")
}
```

Comment: `if 0..<4 ~= x {` You can use pattern match operator

Comment: True, and in that case using `if case 0..<4 = x` is yet another option. I avoided it because it can look confusing to a new programmer and raises more questions.